# Getting error : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: keys should be a string

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, testing

I am getting the error to access the data from the properties file in my selenium UI : How can this be solved ?

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: keys should be a string.
```

I have the following framework. I made it for my self for ease, looks like complicating myself. If any good ideas to better it, please suggest.
Appreciate all suggestions.

Framework contains the following :
1. **config properties file**
2. **utilities class**
3. **Page elements definition class file**
4. **reusable functions class file**
5. **test classes**

`config.properties` file has the following content :

```
url=http://some.com
Email=someuser
Password=somepassword
```

**Utilities** class (`BrowserCalls`) the following code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class BrowserCalls {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public Properties configs = new Properties();
    public String pathToProperties = "path to config.properties file";

    public void invokeChromeBrowser() throws IOException {

        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(pathToProperties);
        pmsConfigs.load(input);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", configs.getProperty("chromepath"));
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        getAndMazimize();

    }

    private void getAndMazimize(){

        driver.get(configs.getProperty("url"));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }


    public void closeChromeBrowser(){

        if(driver != null){

            driver.close();
        }

    }


}
```

Page elements definition class file has the following code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class LoginPageElements {


    //Login page elements
    public static By element1 = By.xpath("/html/head/link[1]");
    public static By username = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login\"]/input/tr1/td1");
    public static By password = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login\"]/input/tr2/td1");
    public static By submitButton = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login\"]/input/tr3/td2/button");
    public static By title = By.xpath("/html/head/title");

}
```

Functionality definition classes to be called by test case classes :

```
import com.automation.PageElements.LoginPageElements;
import com.automation.ReusableFunctions.BrowserCalls;

public class LoginFeature extends BrowserCalls {

    public void userLogin(){

        driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.element1);
        driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.username).sendKeys(configs.getProperty(Email));
        driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.password).sendKeys(configs.getProperty(Password));
        driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.submitButton).click();

    }

}
```

Test Case class is as below :

```
import com.automation.ReusableFunctions.BrowserCalls;
import com.automation.Components.LoginFeature;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LoginTestCase1 extends BrowserCalls {

    @Test (description = "Verify application login")
    public void LoginTest() throws IOException {

        LoginFeature login = new LoginFeature();
        login.invokeChromeBrowser();
        login.userLogin();
        login.closeChromeBrowser();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check what this two statements return like this:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("Email"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("Password"));
```

probably they are returning `null`, and that's why you are getting error.

Try this:

```
public void userLogin(){
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("Email")); // check statement return
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("Password")); // check statement return

        driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.element1);
        driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.username).sendKeys(configs.getProperty("Email"));
        driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.password).sendKeys(configs.getProperty("Password"));
        driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.submitButton).click();

    }
```

PS

```
System.getProperty("key") // should be like this
System.getProperty(key) // not like this
```

Answer (score 2):

Change these two lines to :

```
driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.username).sendKeys(configs.getProperty(Email))
driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.password).sendKeys(configs.getProperty(Password));
```

**To:**

```
driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.username).sendKeys(configs.getProperty("username"))  
driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.password).sendKeys(configs.getProperty("password"));
```

Now talking about the **suggestion** part :

There is some serious issue in this class : **LoginPageElements** , and that is because of absolute **xpath**.

For example : You are using this xpath  : `//*[@id=\"login\"]/input/tr3/td2/button`  to click on **submit** button.

A good alternative would suggest you to use relative xpath something like :

```
//button[text()='Submit']  // This may not work cause you have not shared the HTML for the submit button. Here I am just guessing.
```

different alternative would be to go with :  **sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)** , if and only if the application support clicking on **enter** after providing the `username` and `password`.Something like this in code :

```
driver.findElement(LoginPageElements.password).sendKeys(configs.getProperty("password"+Keys.RETURN));
```

Though as suggested by **@Andrei** , if you are heavily dependent on login as test method , then you should write a relative xpath or any other locator for the submit button instead of `Keys.RETURN`.

Your all xpath are absolute , try to write locators as in this order :

1. **id**
2. **classname**
3. **linkText**
4. **partialLinkText**
5. **tagName**
6. **css selector**
7. **xpath** (Try to be more relative than absolute)

Comment: I would not say, that `sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)` is better, because in this case the submit button will not be tested, if it is clickable and works as expected. I think the most of users will click on the button and not use Enter.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov : That again comes as a use case. If I had to test different module of an application,(By different module I mean internal part) I would not consider login as my test.

Comment: The login test is the first test should be done, and the most important one. If you are not able to login in app, you can't do anything. Automation is about simulating user behavior. That's why I would prefer to locate the button and click on it.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov : Yep agreed, updated the question with the same.  Now as when I do regression of some modules , would I go for login as a test method ? and if you are in such cases where you already have login as a data driven test method where you are testing more than 10-15 username and password , then I would not consider login as a test while doing the regression. Though I would have login test method running before I can make that conclusion.

Comment: @cruisepandey - I have not posted the actual element xpaths. Here are the actual ones : 
    public static By email = By.xpath("//input[@name='email']");
    public static By password = By.xpath("//input[@name='password']");ton
You are correct, absolute ones are not the right way to locate an element. I usually go with the list that you have given it. I just posted it to see why method is failing.

Comment: I see that the xpath you have written contains name attribute. Use name as a locator if it is unique. Something like : driver.findElement(By.name(‘email’)).sendKeys()

Comment: @Andrei Suvorkov, the System.getProperty is working, I have added it for both username and password, and my test case passed. I did not know if it is because of System.getProperty. Because System.getProperty prints null for username and password both.

Comment: @cruisepandey : sure, name is the good way for uniqueness. Taken. I will change it right away

Comment: Did you able to resolve your query ? If yes , then upvote and accept any answer which have helped you to resolve your problem. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I was have troubles with property file, the problem was with line separators, when I opened property file with **Notepad++** all looked fine, but line separators was missing when file was opened with **Notepad**. Possibly it will help

Answer (score 0):

Don't save the Excel table with Excel icon in Excel sheet.
Save the Excel sheet with the button in Eclipse.
Please check the Image Link given below:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJH7O.png)